# ¿Por qué ya no se compila después de agregar la importacion de angular/material y flex-layout en app.module.ts?

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy aprendiendo cómo configurar una aplicación Angular desde un curso en Angular de Coursera y siguiendo las instrucciones dadas [aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZsyJ.png).

Quiero obtener lo siguiente :

[image: Imagen relacionada]

Sin embargo, desde el momento en que traté de configurar para usar los iconos de diseño de materiales incluyendo lo siguiente :

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

En el `<head>` de un archivo llamada `index.html` para hacer uso de iconos de Material Design o cuando he importado el módulo de animaciones angulares, el módulo de materiales angulares, el módulo de diseño flexible y hammerjs en su módulo raíz (src / app / app.module.ts) de la siguiente manera:

```
. . . 
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material'; 
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
. . . 
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({ 
  . . .  
  imports: [    
    . . .,  
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule

  ],   
    . . . 
}) 
. . .
```

informaciones perturbadoras aparecieron en la ventana de la terminal donde lancé `ng -serve open` :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Angular/conFusion$ ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-04-04T15:35:44.292Z                                                          
Hash: f33a63190d4bd2c412cd
Time: 13019ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 17.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 554 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 42.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.42 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-04-04T17:24:33.434Z - Hash: b2fcda6e58f1841f63dd - Time: 276ms          
5 unchanged chunks

webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-04-04T17:24:34.921Z - Hash: 0d064a5411e510594166 - Time: 90ms           
5 unchanged chunks

webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-04-04T17:25:49.626Z - Hash: 3b389b2d7e7da49d2536 - Time: 2402ms         
5 unchanged chunks

webpack: Compiled successfully.
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.

webpack: Compiling...
 90% chunk assets processingERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.

Date: 2018-04-04T17:26:07.426Z - Hash: f1a33b1725570040427a - Time: 3507ms
3 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 18.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 7.62 MB [initial] [rendered]

webpack: Compiled successfully.
webpack: Compiling...
 10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...me/mike/Angular/conFusion/src/main.tsERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(19,5): error TS1005: ',' expected.

Date: 2018-04-04T17:26:28.662Z - Hash: 2a8a46e77727da57bc25 - Time: 13738ms           
3 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 18.9 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 13.5 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5/flex.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in '/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5'

webpack: Failed to compile.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-04-04T17:26:30.669Z - Hash: 9f5010fb06e6583cfda2 - Time: 256ms          
5 unchanged chunks

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5/flex.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in '/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5'

webpack: Failed to compile.
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.

webpack: Compiling...
 30% building modules 1/2 modules 1 active ...ike/Angular/conFusion/src/styles.scssERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.

Date: 2018-04-04T17:57:33.313Z - Hash: 6ce7b7a4c175d6940090 - Time: 3344ms
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 139 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5/flex.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in '/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5'

webpack: Failed to compile.
webpack: Compiling...
Date: 2018-04-04T17:57:42.960Z - Hash: c8e209bc91b81705b83d - Time: 609ms          
4 unchanged chunks
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 140 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ./node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5/flex.es5.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/cdk/bidi' in '/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/esm5'

webpack: Failed to compile.
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
```

Y en my browser, en la ventana `localhost:4200`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### actualización 7 abril:

Rehice las instrucciones y ahora tengo :

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
../node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.


webpack: Failed to compile.
```

en el compilador donde hice `ng serve --open`

Aqui esta lo que podemos ver en `localhost:4200`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que instalé `cdk` con `sudo npm i @angular/cdk` pero nada ayuda :

```
mike@mike-thinks:~/Angular/conFusion/src$ ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 3/3 modules 0 active^C                                       
mike@mike-thinks:~/Angular/conFusion/src$ ng serve --open
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 10% building modules 7/12 modules 5 active .../webpack/hot nonrecursive /^\.\/log$/webpack: wait until bundle finished: /
Date: 2018-04-05T17:07:32.348Z                                                       
Hash: 8a90854ea8d5e97a636f
Time: 5278ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 140 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in ../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/fake-mousedown.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'isFakeMousedownFromScreenReader'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/focus-trap.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'FocusTrap'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/focus-trap.d.ts(8,21): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'FocusTrapFactory'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/focus-trap.d.ts(8,39): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'FocusTrapDeprecatedDirective'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/focus-trap.d.ts(8,69): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'FocusTrapDirective'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/index.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'A11yModule'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/interactivity-checker.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'InteractivityChecker'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/list-key-manager.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CanDisable'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/list-key-manager.d.ts(8,22): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'ListKeyManager'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'AriaLivePoliteness'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(8,30): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'LIVE_ANNOUNCER_ELEMENT_TOKEN'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(8,60): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'LiveAnnouncer'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(8,75): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'LIVE_ANNOUNCER_PROVIDER_FACTORY'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/a11y/live-announcer.d.ts(8,108): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'LIVE_ANNOUNCER_PROVIDER'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/bidi/index.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'Directionality'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/bidi/index.d.ts(8,26): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'DIRECTIONALITY_PROVIDER'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/bidi/index.d.ts(8,51): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'DIR_DOCUMENT'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/bidi/index.d.ts(8,65): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'Direction'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/bidi/index.d.ts(8,76): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'Dir'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/bidi/index.d.ts(8,81): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'BidiModule'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/core.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'coerceBooleanProperty'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/core.d.ts(1,33): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'coerceNumberProperty'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/core.d.ts(1,55): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'ObserveContentModule'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/core.d.ts(1,77): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'ObserveContent'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'UP_ARROW'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,20): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'DOWN_ARROW'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,32): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'RIGHT_ARROW'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,45): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'LEFT_ARROW'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,57): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'PAGE_UP'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,66): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'PAGE_DOWN'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,77): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'HOME'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,83): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'END'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,88): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'ENTER'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,95): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'SPACE'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,102): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'TAB'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,107): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'ESCAPE'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,115): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'BACKSPACE'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/keyboard/keycodes.d.ts(8,126): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'DELETE'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/platform/features.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'getSupportedInputTypes'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/platform/index.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'PlatformModule'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/platform/platform.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'Platform'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/dom-portal-host.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'DomPortalHost'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal-directives.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'TemplatePortalDirective'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal-directives.d.ts(8,35): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'PortalHostDirective'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal-directives.d.ts(8,56): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'PortalModule'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal.d.ts(8,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'Portal'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal.d.ts(8,18): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'PortalHost'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal.d.ts(8,30): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'BasePortalHost'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal.d.ts(8,46): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'ComponentPortal'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/core/portal/portal.d.ts(8,63): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'TemplatePortal'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/sort/sort-header.d.ts(11,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkColumnDef'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/cell.d.ts(9,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkCell'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/cell.d.ts(9,19): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkColumnDef'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/cell.d.ts(9,33): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkHeaderCell'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/row.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkHeaderRow'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/row.d.ts(1,24): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkRow'.
../node_modules/@angular/material/typings/table/table.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/cdk/cdk"' has no exported member 'CdkTable'.


webpack: Failed to compile.
```

#### actualización 21 de Abril :

Parece que el problema surge cuando agrego la importacion de angular/material :

```
...
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material'; 
...
```

Es en este momento que aparece:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
...
src/app/app.module.ts(4,10): error TS2305: Module '"/home/mike/Documents/Coursera/Angular/conFusion/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MaterialModule'. :

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/flex-offset/flex-offset.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/flex/typings/layout-gap/layout-gap.d.ts(9,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/cdk/bidi'.
```

De la misma manera cuando importo flex-layout `import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';` :

No fue el caso con BrowserAnimation que importo en `app.module.ts` con `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';`
Pero cuando intento agregar los imports en `NgModule` :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';


import 'hammerjs';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimation // 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

esto causa un error :

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(17,2): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'BrowserAnimation'.
```

Comment: El proyecto imagino que lo creaste con AngularCLI y de ser asi desde donde ejecutaste los comandos, desde el CMD de tu computadora o desde un editor de texto como ATOM o algun otro?

Comment: @ASASCED Gracias para su reuspuesta, desde el CMD

Comment: Por alguna razón parece que no te cargo todos los elementos necesarios para la ejecución de tu proyecto, llega a pasar en ocasiones por la propia configuración de la ventana de comandos de cada computador pero es raro que no te cargue todos los recursos necesarios para tu proyecto. En este caso yo te recomendaria volver a iniciar un nuevo proyecto y en el caso de que ya hayas hecho codigo solamente tendrias que pasarlo al nuevo proyecto. El nuevo proyecto te recomiendo que lo hagas desde una nueva ventana de comandos que en mi opinion es mucho mejor que la predeterminada de cada computador su